# Firebase -does deleting a key at 1 node affect the same key at another node

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

This question is specifically about how firebase treats whatever data it associates with a key when it creates it. This has nothing to do with how to delete something.

If I have the same key at 2 different nodes, and delete one of them, does the deletion have any effect on the the way firebase treats the key itself? For example keys are added to the database in order by date, would deleting the first key somehow affect the date associated with the second key? Meaning if I was to sort using that second key, it would be sorted incorrectly because the database would recognize it as 'deleted'.

```
@node1
   @MJYtEC3LZyKvFp39WWz // this key gets deleted at another time
       -...: "..."
       -...: "..."
@node2
   @MJYtEC3LZyKvFp39WWz
       -...: "..."
       -...: "..."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no hard relation between those nodes.  They exist completely independently of each other, uniquely identified by the "path" that leads to their location.  The only relationship between them is what you assign to them conceptually in your app.